# Creating a BTC Gateway with ATM Network

Tags: bitcoin-atm

We have a ATM Network and we want to sell and buy BTC or ETH on our ATMs, using our own switch. How can we do it?

Comment: Buy one of these: https://coinatmradar.com/shop/buy-bitcoin-atm/

Comment: We already have the ATMs and Swtich software, just want to know how to interconnect to BTC provider.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch software"? What software do you have that supports buying and selling bitcoins with an ATM?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you. You just need to track the multi-currency balances inside your own gateway. There are a number of ways you could do this but without more information its difficult to help.
We recently built a Ripple based solution which keeps track fiat and virtual deposits using Ripple and you might be able to build or purchase something similar.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not every platform is supported by all software decisions.
Try to use bitcovault software - it supports all means of BTC ATMs almost.
More info is here - https://bitcovault.com/software-for-crypto-atm